# Yii framework: Save uploaded file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm using Yii framework for developing website.
Here, I have a problem in save image file which uploaded to server.

Here is the code which I used for uploading image.

```
<input type="file" onChange="uploadImage(this);">

function uploadImage(obj) {
    var request_url = server_url + "uploadImage";
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("photo", obj.files[0]);

    $.ajax({
            url: request_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType:false
        });
}
```

And in server part, I can see the file has uploaded but can't get the file.

```
public function actionUploadImage() {

   if (ISSET($_FILES['photo'])) {
       var_dump('is set photo');
       $temp = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('photo');
       var_dump($temp);
   }
}
```

It returns "is set photo" and "array(0){}".
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are uploading images using `jquery/ajax`. You need to include jquery and their corresponding function.

Here is one of tutorial to upload images using jquery -

```
http://www.9lessons.info/2013/09/multiple-ajax-image-upload-jquery.html
```

You could google for other tutorials.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. And I've a question.
So you mean if i use jquery/ajax, i can't receive the file with CUploadedFile in Yii framework?

Comment: you may be retreive but you cant move that to folder

Comment: how can i retrieve it?